# Do upvoted questions that are put on hold make you lose upvotes if closed?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I had a question upvoted twice and put on-hold (ignoring I got "net-votes" of 2 and still got put on-hold for "not being clear") if the post got closed, does the reputation points I gain from there go away as in lose them?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

You keep the reputation you earn from a post as long as it is not deleted from the site... and even then, there are special caveats for posts that are over 60 days old...

Now, if a question is put on hold and it's never clarified (since your post was put on hold as "unclear what you're asking"), you should still be working to clarify your question so that it can be reopened. Be sure to edit your question to add details as requested by the close explanation and (if there are any) comments on the question.

Comment: how could a question be deleted from the site?

Comment: That information is here, in the deletion FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?s=1|92.1857 You might be interested in reviewing some of the questions with the [tag:faq] tag here for all sorts of helpful information.

Comment: is there a reason I got a downvote